# Simple factory and IOC

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inversion-of-control, factory

I have a `class A{}` `class B:A{}` `class C:A{}` and `class D{}`
D has methods that need to to use B and methods that need to use `C`.

in the future I will probably have more classes that inherit from `A` that `D`will need to use

Should `D` have a constructor like:

1. public `D(B b, C c)`
2. or should `A` get a simple factory `(F)` that will return the
   correct class. and then the constructor will be `public D(F f)`

`F` will have a `CreateInstance` method that will get enum and return the correct type.

full injection would keep all in the composition root.
simple factory would simplify the constructor.

Comment: Does the class A is an abstract class or interface?

Comment: Its abstract class in ny case but if theres a diffrence id love answer for both cases.

Comment: implement it as interfaces so you can inherent many `types`

Comment: What would happen when you initialize `D` with `new D(new C(), new B())` instead of `new D(new B(), new C())`? Would that break D? If this would break `D`, it means that you violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @Steven fixed, stupid mistake thanks!

Comment: What exactly did you fix?

Comment: public D(B b, C c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you need to be mindful of here is introducing opaque dependencies via the factory approach.

At this point in time, D depends on B **and** C. Using a constructor like:

```
public D(B b, C c)
{
}
```

makes the dependencies transparent. I.e. it's clear what this class needs to do its job and these things can be provided directly. Furthermore, automated testing is a little easier as you can provide fakes directly without having to provide a fake factory that provides the other fakes.

Using a factory reduces this clarity, but does add convenience, and a degree of future-proofing by reducing the number of dependencies that must be passed in.

Personally, I would stick with providing the dependencies directly until the constructor signature was unwieldy or a higher level abstraction, like a factory, was clearly needed. The fact that the class depends on **both** `B` **and** `C` gives off a clear design message that an abstraction like a factory might obscure.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, in the case where B and C implement the same interface the right way to do this is to pass a `factory`. Also I'd avoid depending on a concrete type but instead depend on an interface. If you have to get specifically these 2 then or add for each another interface and depend on that interface, or go for the factory.

(*See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481859/composite-design-pattern-how-to-pass-results-from-one-component-into-another/38481988#38481988) for a more complete example*)

```
public enum XTypes
{
    A,B,C...
}

public interface IXFactory
{
    IX GetX(XTypes xType);
}

public interface IX
{
    void SomeMethod()
}

//And I'd do A as an abstract class and rename to XBase
public class A : IX
{
    public void SomeMethod() {}
}

public class D
{
    public D(IXFactory xFactory)
    {
        XFactory = xFactory;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var x1 = XFactory.GetX(XTypes.A);
        var x2 = XFactory.GetX(XTypes.C);
    }

    public IXFactory XFactory { get; set; }
}
```

I personally would not put a factory in the following cases:

1. I only need a specific dependency implementation for the entire life of the program.
2. I need all implementations of that dependency and execute all of them (just depend on `IEnumerable<IDependency>`
3. There is only a single implementation of that dependency in the entire code (it is easy to add a factory - so when one day I might need then I'll add)

---

In addition it is nice to have the `IX` itself declaring what is his key (in this case the `enum`) and then the factory's implementation is really clean.

**Also** - in `Castle Windosr` (and I'm sure that in other Ioc Containers too) there is a `TypedFactoryFacility` that you can manipulate by implementing a `ITypedFactoryComponentSelector` and then you don't even need to implement the factory yourself.

*If instead of `enum` you will have an object you can change the `IX` to `IX<XRequestBase>` and then the `TypedFactoryFacility` will map and work automatically :)